# How to display total qty product in list.pthml

Tags: magento2

Under product name, I need to display total stock quantity of product.

I have used below code:

```
<?php
     $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getQty(), null, true);
 ?>
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
     echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getQty(), 'quantity_and_stock_status'); 
?>
```

But it's returning 0 for all.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

**getQty() function returns zero or invalid value because the product collection does not return qty field and it's value with it.**

So, for that, you'll need to modify the function which is returning the product collection and modify it in a way that it also sends qty value along with it.

1.First, you'll need to override PHTML file, so for that create ***Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2.Now, Create PHTML file located at ***Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml***

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

?>
<?php
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate.FoundThis

/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 */
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()) :?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('We can\'t find products matching the selection.')) ?></div></div>
<?php else :?>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?= $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
    if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    } else {
        $viewMode = 'list';
        $imageDisplayArea = 'category_page_list';
        $showDescription = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
    }
    /**
     * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
     */
    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <div class="products wrapper <?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?> products-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
        <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) :?>
            <li class="item product product-item">
                <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewMode ?>">
                    <?php
                    $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $imageDisplayArea);
                    if ($pos != null) {
                        $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                            . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php // Product Image ?>
                    <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                       class="product photo product-item-photo"
                       tabindex="-1">
                        <?= $productImage->toHtml() ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <?php
                            $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                        ?>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <a class="product-item-link"
                               href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>">
                                <?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                            <?php echo "Total Qty: ".$_product->getQty(); ?>
                        </strong>
                        <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()) :?>
                            <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                            <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                                <div class="actions-primary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form"
                                              data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                                              action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>"
                                              method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                   name="product"
                                                   value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="<?= /* @noEscape */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>"
                                                   value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
                                            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                    class="action tocart primary">
                                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    <?php else :?>
                                        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()) :?>
                                            <div class="stock available"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                        <?php else :?>
                                            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?= strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $block->escapeHtmlAttr($position) : '' ?>>
                                    <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')) :?>
                                        <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_product)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php if ($showDescription) :?>
                                <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                    <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($_product->getProductUrl()) ?>"
                                       title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                       class="action more"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Learn More')) ?></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) :?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {
                    "product_sku": "<?= $block->escapeJs($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

3.Now create di.xml to override the collection function so that it returns attribute qty as well to the PHTML file. ***Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct"/>
</config>
```

4.Now create the override file mentioned in di.xml ***Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php***

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Config;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Element;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render;
use Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data;

/**
 * Product list
 * @api
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct implements IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * Default toolbar block name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_defaultToolbarBlock = Toolbar::class;

    /**
     * Product Collection
     *
     * @var AbstractCollection
     */
    protected $_productCollection;

    /**
     * Catalog layer
     *
     * @var Layer
     */
    protected $_catalogLayer;

    /**
     * @var PostHelper
     */
    protected $_postDataHelper;

    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $urlHelper;

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PostHelper $postDataHelper
     * @param Resolver $layerResolver
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param Data $urlHelper
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        Data $urlHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->_postDataHelper = $postDataHelper;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve loaded product collection
     *
     * The goal of this method is to choose whether the existing collection should be returned
     * or a new one should be initialized.
     *
     * It is not just a caching logic, but also is a real logical check
     * because there are two ways how collection may be stored inside the block:
     *   - Product collection may be passed externally by 'setCollection' method
     *   - Product collection may be requested internally from the current Catalog Layer.
     *
     * And this method will return collection anyway,
     * even when it did not pass externally and therefore isn't cached yet
     *
     * @return AbstractCollection
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            $this->_productCollection = $this->initializeProductCollection();
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Get catalog layer model
     *
     * @return Layer
     */
    public function getLayer()
    {
        return $this->_catalogLayer;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve loaded category collection
     *
     * @return AbstractCollection
     */
    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        return $this->_getProductCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current view mode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMode()
    {
        if ($this->getChildBlock('toolbar')) {
            return $this->getChildBlock('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
        }

        return $this->getDefaultListingMode();
    }

    /**
     * Get listing mode for products if toolbar is removed from layout.
     * Use the general configuration for product list mode from config path catalog/frontend/list_mode as default value
     * or mode data from block declaration from layout.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getDefaultListingMode()
    {
        // default Toolbar when the toolbar layout is not used
        $defaultToolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();
        $availableModes = $defaultToolbar->getModes();

        // layout config mode
        $mode = $this->getData('mode');

        if (!$mode || !isset($availableModes[$mode])) {
            // default config mode
            $mode = $defaultToolbar->getCurrentMode();
        }

        return $mode;
    }

    /**
     * Need use as _prepareLayout - but problem in declaring collection from another block.
     * (was problem with search result)
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();

        $this->addToolbarBlock($collection);

        if (!$collection->isLoaded()) {
            $collection->load();
        }

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Add toolbar block from product listing layout
     *
     * @param Collection $collection
     */
    private function addToolbarBlock(Collection $collection)
    {
        $toolbarLayout = $this->getToolbarFromLayout();

        if ($toolbarLayout) {
            $this->configureToolbar($toolbarLayout, $collection);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Toolbar block from layout or a default Toolbar
     *
     * @return Toolbar
     */
    public function getToolbarBlock()
    {
        $block = $this->getToolbarFromLayout();

        if (!$block) {
            $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, uniqid(microtime()));
        }

        return $block;
    }

    /**
     * Get toolbar block from layout
     *
     * @return bool|Toolbar
     */
    private function getToolbarFromLayout()
    {
        $blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName();

        $toolbarLayout = false;

        if ($blockName) {
            $toolbarLayout = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName);
        }

        return $toolbarLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve additional blocks html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdditionalHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('additional');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve list toolbar HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getToolbarHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }

    /**
     * Set collection.
     *
     * @param AbstractCollection $collection
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add attribute.
     *
     * @param array|string|integer|Element $code
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addAttribute($code)
    {
        $this->_getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect($code);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price block template.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPriceBlockTemplate()
    {
        return $this->_getData('price_block_template');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Catalog Config object
     *
     * @return Config
     */
    protected function _getConfig()
    {
        return $this->_catalogConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Sort By fields from Category Data
     *
     * @param Category $category
     * @return $this
     */
    public function prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($category)
    {
        if (!$this->getAvailableOrders()) {
            $this->setAvailableOrders($category->getAvailableSortByOptions());
        }
        $availableOrders = $this->getAvailableOrders();
        if (!$this->getSortBy()) {
            $categorySortBy = $this->getDefaultSortBy() ?: $category->getDefaultSortBy();
            if ($categorySortBy) {
                if (!$availableOrders) {
                    $availableOrders = $this->_getConfig()->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();
                }
                if (isset($availableOrders[$categorySortBy])) {
                    $this->setSortBy($categorySortBy);
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        $identities = [];

        $category = $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory();
        if ($category) {
            $identities[] = Product::CACHE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_TAG . '_' . $category->getId();
        }

        //Check if category page shows only static block (No products)
        if ($category->getData('display_mode') == Category::DM_PAGE) {
            return $identities;
        }

        foreach ($this->_getProductCollection() as $item) {
            // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Performance.ForeachArrayMerge
            $identities = array_merge($identities, $item->getIdentities());
        }

        return $identities;
    }

    /**
     * Get post parameters
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAddToCartPostParams(Product $product)
    {
        $url = $this->getAddToCartUrl($product, ['_escape' => false]);
        return [
            'action' => $url,
            'data' => [
                'product' => (int) $product->getEntityId(),
                ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->urlHelper->getEncodedUrl($url),
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get product price.
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductPrice(Product $product)
    {
        $priceRender = $this->getPriceRender();

        $price = '';
        if ($priceRender) {
            $price = $priceRender->render(
                FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                $product,
                [
                    'include_container' => true,
                    'display_minimal_price' => true,
                    'zone' => Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
                    'list_category_page' => true
                ]
            );
        }

        return $price;
    }

    /**
     * Specifies that price rendering should be done for the list of products.
     * (rendering happens in the scope of product list, but not single product)
     *
     * @return Render
     */
    protected function getPriceRender()
    {
        return $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default')
            ->setData('is_product_list', true);
    }

    /**
     * Configures product collection from a layer and returns its instance.
     *
     * Also in the scope of a product collection configuration, this method initiates configuration of Toolbar.
     * The reason to do this is because we have a bunch of legacy code
     * where Toolbar configures several options of a collection and therefore this block depends on the Toolbar.
     *
     * This dependency leads to a situation where Toolbar sometimes called to configure a product collection,
     * and sometimes not.
     *
     * To unify this behavior and prevent potential bugs this dependency is explicitly called
     * when product collection initialized.
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    private function initializeProductCollection()
    {
        $layer = $this->getLayer();
        /* @var $layer Layer */
        if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
            $this->setCategoryId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
        }

        // if this is a product view page
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')) {
            // get collection of categories this product is associated with
            $categories = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')
                ->getCategoryCollection()->setPage(1, 1)
                ->load();
            // if the product is associated with any category
            if ($categories->count()) {
                // show products from this category
                $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator())->getId());
            }
        }

        $origCategory = null;
        if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
            try {
                $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($this->getCategoryId());
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                $category = null;
            }

            if ($category) {
                $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
            }
        }
        $collection = $layer->getProductCollection();

        $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

        if ($origCategory) {
            $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
        }

        $this->addToolbarBlock($collection);

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'catalog_block_product_list_collection',
            ['collection' => $collection]
        );
        $collection->joinField(
            'qty', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left'
        );
        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Configures the Toolbar block with options from this block and configured product collection.
     *
     * The purpose of this method is the one-way sharing of different sorting related data
     * between this block, which is responsible for product list rendering,
     * and the Toolbar block, whose responsibility is a rendering of these options.
     *
     * @param ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @return void
     */
    private function configureToolbar(Toolbar $toolbar, Collection $collection)
    {
        // use sortable parameters
        $orders = $this->getAvailableOrders();
        if ($orders) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        $sort = $this->getSortBy();
        if ($sort) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        $dir = $this->getDefaultDirection();
        if ($dir) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        $modes = $this->getModes();
        if ($modes) {
            $toolbar->setModes($modes);
        }
        // set collection to toolbar and apply sort
        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);
        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
    }
}
```

**Done**. It should work fine now, you can modify PHTML file as per your look need and design. getQty() function should work correctly now in PHTML file.

Change Vendor and Module name as per your module details in mentioned files. Or if you wish to directly download the module, here's a GitHub link for that, ***https://github.com/nathaodedara/magento-displayqtybelowproduct***